# Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) - Sdk and user assembly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, linker

My app is crashing at start-up itself when I am setting Linking option to *Sdk and User assembly*. Getting below exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object  at
>   Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x001f6] in
>   <9fc8067708b844e2bf1259cff6b751e7>:0  at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr
>   jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   :0 at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.8(intptr,intptr,intptr)

I have enabled ProGuard in properties. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your code will may also be removed If you have no static reference even if you set the link as **Sdk and User assembly** .You can check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80717/link-all-assemblies-causes-my-app-to-crash and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#linker-behavior

Comment: You can check my blog here https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688 where I have explained in detail how to perform Linking!